# how to make an effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

please help to fix it effect parallax
 
on the [page](http://prozaik.16mb.com/works/upgrade/markup_mortan/), I tried to use the effect of parallax.

js:

```
$objWindow = $(window);

$('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
    var $bgObj = $(this);

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        console.log(11);

        var yPos = -($objWindow.scrollTop() / $bgObj.data('speed'));

        var coords = '100% '+ yPos + 'px';

        console.log(coords);

        $bgObj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords});
    });
```

the problem is that when the scroll does not change the y-coordinate at the position in the block backgrounds #apex

Answer (score -1):

you've made a mistake:

**yours:**

```
$bgObj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords});
```

change this like below:

```
$bgObj.css({ 'background-position': coords});
```